# Acquia Dev Desktop Installation error-unable to realloc 1073741832 bytes

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

i was installing "Acquia Dev Desktop " on my windows 7 PC. Link to Acquia dev desktop https://docs.acquia.com/dev-desktop

During the installation process it showed the error message

> Fatal Error Installer-**Unable to realloc 1073741832 bytes**

Can anyone tell me whatscausing the problem and how can i fix it.

Acquia does not have a free support forum